# Zooming datasets in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I have overlayed two datasets, a boundary map and a point map in d3.js. I want to be able to zoom both datasets at the same time. With the current code, only the point map responds to the zoom. How can I zoom both datasets at the same time

The code is shown below

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",260)
    .attr("height",400)

d3.json("/Maps/iowastate.json",function (data){
    var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
    var projection =d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(250)
    //.translate([0,0]);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class","area")
        .attr("fill","black");




d3.csv("/Maps/detectors.csv",function (d){
    var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
        .data(d)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.StartLong,d.StartLat])[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d,i) {
               return projection([d.StartLong,d.StartLat])[1];
       })
       .attr("r", 0.1)
       .style("fill", "red");
    //console.log(projection(d[0].StartLat))
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom",function(){
        group.attr("transform","translate("+ 
        d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        group.selectAll("path")  
        .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        });
    canvas.call(zoom)
    })
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom",function(){
        group.attr("transform","translate("+ 
        d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        group.selectAll("path")  
        .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        });
    canvas.call(zoom)


})
```

Comment: Apply the modifications you're making in the zoom handler function to both layers.

Comment: Lars, could you be more specific? I taught calling the zoom for each layer should resolve that. Is there anything  I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing that, you are calling the exact code twice (which has the same effect as calling it once). You need to keep references to both of your `group` variables and apply the transformations to both.

Comment: Ooooo... great!. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the right modifications, but twice to the same set of elements instead of the two different layers. To make it work, keep a reference to the other `group` (e.g. by using different variable names) and apply the transformations to both groups.